# How to get ButtonPress and ButtonRelease events from middle button in Synaptics' clickpad?

Tags: xorg, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have a Synaptics touchpad, with a 3 buttons clickpad (it is a ThinkPad X1 Carbon with physical buttons). Using xev, when I click the middle button I get the corresponding ButtonPress and ButtonRelease buttons. However, if the click is long, I do not get any event. This makes impossible to drag with the middle button.

What it should do (and it was working this way in my previous configuration using Archlinux) is to generate a ButtonPress event when I press it and a ButtonRelease when I release it, and of course also all the events in the middle (like mouse movement or other buttons clicks). The left and right buttons are working well.

I guess this may be related to some option that has something to do with the possibility of pressing this button to scroll, but I have tried any combination of options I could think of using synclient and I could not find the right one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.